# De src a dist angular

Tags: angular, electron

> Tengo definido un import de esta manera

```
import { print } from "../expensas/src/assets/print";
```

> Pero cuando lo compilo usando electron no lo encuentra, ya que ahora
> lo tiene que buscar en dist o release. como puedo hacer?. Gracias
>
> Agrego lo que tengo

```
  "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon.png",
              "src/favicon.icns",
              "src/favicon.256x256.png",
              "src/favicon.512x512.png",
              "src/print.js",
              "src/print.html",
              "src/barcode_sample.js"
            ],
```

Cuando compilo a windows (Angular+Electron), sigue busando en scr y me dice que no lo encuentra.

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo angular.json agrega en la propiedad "assets" la ruta del file que requieres que este disponible cuando compiles desde el directorio dist. Quedaría algo así:

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "assets": [
              "src/print" // Este seria el file.
            ],
```

Comment: Hola MIguel y gracias por responder.